# Android-Universal-Image-Loader ImagePager - How to avoid the activity back to first page when device rotated

Tags: universal-image-loader

The ImagePagerActivity show the page 1 (In scrollview) when i rotate the device. How to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String STATE_POSITION = "STATE_POSITION";

    ViewPager pager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
        }

        // ...

        pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    ...
}
```